# Parsing HTML String in QT

Tags: html, qt, qt4

I want to parse HTML String in Qt,

basically i have `QTextEdit` object (allowed rich text), and when some body paste Rich text (copied from MSWORD or similar) in `QTextEdit`, i want to have the style information.

I have my own structure to store the style imformation as below. can anyone tell me how can i parse HTML after i get the html from `QTextEdit`? 
any existing method?,

P.S : i am using QT version 4.1.4 (due to project reason) so i can't use QT classes added after 4.1.4.

Thanks in advance.

```
typedef struct styleset {
  QString font;
  QString size;
  bool bold;
  bool italics;
  bool underline;
  QString color;
}STYLESET;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that MsWord Rtf format is not the same as Qt rich text. QTextEdit don't recognize Rtf.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can create a `QDomDocument` then set its content with `QDomDocument::setContent( const QString & text, ...)`.

Qt 4.1 Doc says:

> This function reads the XML document
>   from the string text. Since text is
>   already a Unicode string, no encoding
>   detection is done.

Once you `QDomDocument` is loaded, you can mess around with nodes, attributes etc to fill your struct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QTextCursor` to iterate through the `QTextDocument` associated with texteditor and retrieve character style information with `QTextCursor::charFormat()`.